# Converting an expression in string to boolean in procedure (PL/SQL) Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Is it possible to to run an expression which is in a string format in a procedure?

I have a string which is "((TRUE AND TRUE) OR (TRUE AND FALSE) OR (FALSE AND TRUE))"

Now I need to validate its trueness. How should I do it in the procedure.

To give a detailed explanation the string is returned from another query which is not in my control and I can write functions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097777/pl-sql-convert-string-to-boolean) but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097777/pl-sql-convert-string-to-boolean) would give me only true from a boolean which is in string. I have a different requirement here, Is it possible to do it in procedure? If so how?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
     set serveroutput on
     declare
       expr varchar2(1000) := '((TRUE AND TRUE) OR (TRUE AND FALSE) OR (FALSE AND TRUE))';
       i int;
      begin
        execute immediate 'begin if '||expr||' then :a := 1; else :a := 0; end if; end;' using out i;
        if i = 1 then
          dbms_output.put_line('TRUE');
        else
          dbms_output.put_line('FALSE');
        end if;
      end;
      /
    TRUE                                                                            

   declare
     expr varchar2(1000) := '((TRUE AND TRUE) AND (TRUE AND FALSE) AND (FALSE AND TRUE))';
     i int;
    begin
      execute immediate 'begin if '||expr||' then :a := 1; else :a := 0; end if; end;' using out i;
      if i = 1 then
        dbms_output.put_line('TRUE');
      else
        dbms_output.put_line('FALSE');
      end if;
    end;
    /
    FALSE
```